# Is there any way to change linearly polarized emag wave polarization as it is propagating without altering propagation direction or Az/El patterns?

Tags: rf, antenna, electromagnetism, microwave

Let's say I have a vertically polarized emag wave, but I want to convert it to horizontal after it has already been emitted from the source antenna without altering its propagation direction *or* Az/El pattern in the process (so essentially rotate the E-plane polarization by 90 degrees, but the Az/El farfield patterns remain the same as they were before).  Are there ways of accomplishing this?

I am asking because I have a vertically polarized antenna design with a set of Az/El patterns that meet the specs I want, but I basically need to duplicate this for a horizontally polarized case, and due to various constraints, it is not as simple as rotating the source antenna by 90 degrees to do so (partly because Az/El are not the same radiation patterns in the existing vertically polarized design, and I need nearly identical Az/El patterns for the h-pol case).

This is for a K-Band application, and I can't really get into much more detail beyond that.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. However, you should probably edit the question and at least mention the wavelength or frequency you are using. Also, how much room do you have to work with? Anything that can alter the polarization is liable to be on the same size scale as the wavelength or existing antenna. Don't answer in the comments. Add detail to the question.

Comment: Are you asking for a waveplate?

Comment: Just google for "polarization converters".